# C# program to listen to another application for certain keyboard stokes

Tags: c#, listener, hook

I want to create a simple C# application that will listen to another application for a certain keyboard press or event. For example, I have an excel file that I want to monitor that if when a user will press the "a" key, my C# program will show a message box saying "you press the letter a". Aside from that, I want my C# program to listen to that excel file only.

I've heard about the hooking thing and I don't know where to start, like the very basic of it or is there any other alternate solutions?

Any reply would be much appreciated! More power!

Comment: Sounds like a keylogger.

Comment: Need to have Inter Process Communication, if it other application is yours... Else go for hooking

Comment: what if you log all the key pressed with time but that should be a continuous process...

Comment: As @Matthijs said it _does_ sounds malicious. However I've dealt with a similar problem myself (It was malicious too, but for fun only) and I wouldn't like not getting the help I needed. Anyhow, try reading [This](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex) it looks like that's all you need to it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies... do you know where can I start or any better tutorial aside from the msdn. :)

Comment: I'm trying to create a small app that will prevent a user from pressing a certain key so to avoid any critical changes in the file and get the name of the users who pressed the forbidden button. :)